# Can a step function be "smoothed" yet have the same definite integral?

Tags: real-analysis, smooth-functions, step-function

If one has a [step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Step_function) with an infinite number of intervals 
$$s(x) = \sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty \alpha_i \chi_{A_i}(x)$$
and its integral 
$$I_s(t)=\int_0^ts(x)dx,$$
does there exist a smooth, continuous function $c(x)$ with integral $$I_c(t)=\int_0^tc(x)dx$$
such that
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{I_s(t)}{I_s(t)} = 1
$$
and if so, what might be a method of finding $c(x)$? Does it have a closed form? Is it unique? If not, why? I've looked at sum smoothing and asymptotic expansions of said smoothed sums, but no source I've read thus far has commented on the integral of these smooth sums, and I haven't the slightest idea of where to look for more information or how to solve this problem. Incidentally, if anyone has any further reading on the topic I'd be much obliged.

Comment: $I_s$ is an arbitrary continuous piecewise-linear function passing through $(0,0)$. If you can find a smooth function $I_c$ satisfying your limit and passing through $(0,0)$, then $c$ is simply its derivative. I don't see the need of referring to $s$ and $c$ at all...

Comment: Are the coefficients $\alpha_i$ allowed to be negative? If so, then $I_s$ could zigzag across the $x$-axis, making it difficult for $I_c/I_s$ to converge. Indeed, take the triangular wave $I_s\big(x\in[-1,1]\big)=|x|,\;I_s(x+2)=I_s(x)$, which has vertices at integers $n$, and $I_s(2n)=0$. Any smooth function $I_c$ either has $I_c(2n)\neq0$, in which case $I_c/I_s$ is unbounded there; or $I_c(2n)=0$, in which case $I_c/I_s$ has two different limits from the left and right, $\pm I_c'(2n)$ according to L'Hopital's rule. So $I_c/I_s$ cannot converge to $1$.

Comment: You are aware of that convolution of $s$ with a [bump function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function) $\phi$ yields a smooth function whose local mean value is the same as $s$ ? Then $ \lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{I_s(t)}{I_{s \ast \phi}(t)} $ converges iff $I_s$ is non-zero and $\alpha_i = o(I_s)$